Green function in scattering theory
I'm having a bit of trouble with a step in scattering theory.
Context:
The Schrödinger equation for a two-body scattering problem can be written as:
$$
(E - H_0) |\psi\rangle = V |\psi\rangle.
$$
Here, $ V $ is the interaction potential, and $ H_0 $ is the free particle Hamiltonian.
By rearranging this equation, we obtain:
$$
(E - H_0) |\psi\rangle = V |\psi\rangle.
$$
Thus:
$$
|\psi^\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{E - H_0 \pm i \varepsilon}V |\psi^\pm\rangle.
$$
By adding the homogeneous solution, we get:
$$
|\psi^\pm\rangle = |\psi_0\rangle + \frac{1}{E - H_0 \pm i \varepsilon} V|\psi^\pm\rangle.
$$
Problem:
Now comes my problem. From what I've seen, in order to calculate
$$
\langle \mathbf{r}'|\frac{1}{E - H_0 \pm i \varepsilon}|\mathbf{r}\rangle
$$
we end up with:
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{k}' \langle \mathbf{r} | \frac{1}{E - H_0 \pm i\varepsilon} | \mathbf{k}' \rangle \exp\left(-i \mathbf{k}' \cdot \mathbf{r}'\right).
$$
It is said here that we can replace $ E $ by $ \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} $, and of course $ H_0^{-1} | \mathbf{k}' \rangle = \frac{2m}{\hbar^2 k'^2} | \mathbf{k}' \rangle $.
What I don't understand is why we can replace $ E $ by $ \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} $. It doesn't make sense to me because $ E $ is the eigenvalue of the whole Schrödinger's equation, not just the free part.

$E$ is (usually) assumed to be in the continuous spectrum of both $H_0$ and $H$, as any decent book on scattering theory should explain. Note that indeed your $\psi^\pm$ solves the SE only if $\psi_0$ solves the unpertubed one with the same energy.


What I don't understand is why we can replace $ E $ by $ \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} $. It doesn't make sense to me because $ E $ is the eigenvalue of the whole Schrödinger's equation, not just the free part.

If $E$ is positive, and if $m$ is positive (which I assume it is), and if $k$ is real, then you can always write:
$$
E = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}\;,
$$
since $\hbar^2$ is positive and the square of a real number is positive.
You are basically just redefining the variable of interest from $E$ to $k$.
